# check consecutive dates matlab

Tags: matlab, date, days

I have a cell array containing dates:

```
unique_days{1,1} =     '15/03/2012';
unique_days{2,1} =     '16/03/2012';
unique_days{3,1} =     '17/03/2012';
unique_days{4,1} =     '19/03/2012';
unique_days{5,1} =     '20/03/2012';
```

I would like to check if the cell array contains consecutive days.
In particular I would like to create a vector `consecutive_days` that contains 1 if `unique_days{i+1,1}` is the day after `unique_day{i,1}`

In this case `consectutive_days` shoud be `= [1 1 0 1]`

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`datenum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and then [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html):

```
consecutive_days = diff(datenum(unique_days, 'dd/mm/yyyy')).'==1;
```